# How to change icon of msi installer package in vs2008 and change user interface screen after creating package for c# projects

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-3.0, windows-installer

I am trying to change the icon of msi installer package. I didnt found any solution for that. Also i tried to change user interface of msi installer package. I got some skins for that interface,but that is trail version.. Any one knows please help me regarding the above question.

Answer (score 3):

The icon is the standard icon for .msi files. You can´t modify it from within the Setup Project in Visual Studio 2008. The screens used in the Setup Project can´t be modified either from within Visual Studio 2008. The best bet would probably be to look at other 3rd part providers. One example is the [Skin Crafter Installer](http://www.skincrafter.com/products/skincrafter-installer). You can also use [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) and create your customized dialogs yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Visual Studio to change the setup.exe icon. Take the following steps.

Build your setup project

Open the setup.exe file use just
        build, File -> Open -> File

Right click the Icon node in the
        file explorer window and you can change and save.

Comment: I tried to change the icon of setup.exe file.,but iam not able to save that file. it is showing the message cannot save project\setup.exe. if any other plz let me know.

thanks for ur reply.

Comment: Yaa I got the solution. Thank u very much.. But i have a question with u. Why cant we change the icon for msi installer file. if we can change plz reply to this.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As easy solution is to convert the msi to an exe using a program such as "Msi to Exe Converter". The trial does not allow to change the icon. To change the icon use Visual studio. Open the exe as a file and delete the current icon resource. Then add an icon resource by importing the icon you want. Save and done.